# List all Tables,Indexes, Views, Procedures, Materialize views from PostgreSQL version 13

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to list all the created Tables,Indexes, Views, Procedures, Materialize views from all Databases. By 'created' I mean not all the postgres default tables,views etc. I found a way to list all tables but it's per database and couldn't find a way to list all tables from all databases.

```
SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables WHERE schemaname != 'pg_catalog' AND schemaname != 'information_schema';
```

```
SELECT viewname FROM pg_views WHERE schemaname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema') AND viewname !~ '^pg_';
```

Can't find a way to list all from all databases , hope someone has an easy solution for this.

Comment: As you found pg_catalog and the information_schema is per database.  What about connecting to each database and extracting the information?

Comment: Yeah I know it's possible to do this per each db, I though maybe there's a way to run this once for all databases.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to connect to each database seperatly, these details are not revealed in other databases as this might reveal sensitive information. You can query pg_database to retrieve a list of all databases and use that information to write a program that connects to all the databases (if you have the privileges to do so).